# Trouble installing/configuring Vundle

Tags: vim, installation, bundle-install, vundle

I am following the Vundle install instructions from https://github.com/gmarik/vundle
but I run into trouble at step #3 (issuing the command `:BundleInstall` from within VIM). I get an error, `E492: Not an editor command: BundleInstall`

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit) and have the following VIM related packages installed:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep vim
vim                         install
vim-addon-manager           install
vim-common                  install
vim-doc                     install
vim-runtime                 install
vim-scripts                 install
vim-tiny                    install
```

They are all default versions from the Ubuntu Saucy repos.

I have the output of my vim `:version`,`$tree ~/.vim`, and `echo $PATH` here:
http://pastebin.com/pLB1trsG

Attributes of my .vimrc file:

```
$ ls -la | grep .vimrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   1027 Dec 24 15:28 .vimrc
```

Contents of my .vimrc file:
http://pastebin.com/RKYzBZZG

If you can think of anything else that might be helpful in diagnosing the problem, please let me know.

Comment: Are you logged in as root? If you are not are you using sudo to run vim?

Comment: I was not logged in as root; however, using sudo vim produces the same error when issuing the :BundleInstall command.

Comment: The reason I asked was that the vimrc file was owned by root. Which means things are might be mis configured. Using `sudo vim` uses roots  vimrc and .vim which you don't want. How come the vimrc belongs to root?

Comment: That was actually my first guess as to the problem. I tried setting the owner as thomas but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not have vunlde installed correctly.

```
git clone https://github.com/gmarik/vundle.git ~/.vim/bundle/vundle
```